# Tap Counter App - Save Count on exit of App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a simple tap counter app, consisting of a button - which is pressed to count and a label which displays the count.
I would like to save the count on exit of the screen/app, or if the home button is pressed or if the app crashes.

Here is my code so far:

```
h file:
int counter;

@interface tapcounter : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *count;
}
-(IBAction)click;

m file:
-(IBAction)click {
counter++;
count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];
```

Any ideas on how I can best implement this?  I am brand new to Xcode so will appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: ok, if that's the best way

Comment: Regardless of the fact that its not a huge amount of data, saving to a file is the only way to persistently store data onto the device(or a db of course). Everything else stays in memory and is lost when application finishes running.

Comment: yeap, save it to your file or nsuserdefualts

Comment: any tutorials or code I can use to implement for nsuserdefaults?  I'm not sure how to implement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults to store stuff permanently

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:Any object you want forKey:any Key you want];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

When application closes or crashes you can catch that by adding notifications:

Add this in  your viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveCount) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveCount) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
```

Do the saving part in saveCount method

```
-(void)saveCount
{
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [userDefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter] forKey:@"saveCount"];
 [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

When you want to read the variable again use this - may be in ViewDidLoad

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *countString= [userDefaults objectForKey:@"saveCount"];
NSLog(@"Your Count: %@",count);

//checking if data in user defaults is not empty
if(countString.length>0)
{
count.text=count;
counter=[countString intValue];
}

else
{
  //for first time 
  counter=0;
  count.text=@"0";
}
```

assuming yourlocalCountVariable is incremented every time the button is pressed.

Comment: You have to read the value from the count variable and assign it to your label and the next time when button is pressed you have to start from the value from NSUserDefaults not '0'.

Comment: I have tried implementing some of the above code but I'm getting errors.  Thee 3 lines give me errors:

NSLog(@"Your Count: %@",count);
yourlable.text=count;
yourlocalCountVariable=[count intValue];

Comment: @Mustafa I have edited everything , it will work fine now. You could have just renamed those variables its ok try n tell me nw.

Comment: I am still getting some errors, I have added a screenshot of these to the Q above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27578/discussion-between-mustafa-and-satheeshwaran)

Answer (score 1):

By far, the easiest way would be `NSUserDefaults`. Try this to save:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:count forKey:@"count"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

To retrieve it, use this:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"count"]) {
    NSInteger count = [NSUserDefaults integerForKey:@"count"];
    //use the value here
}
```

Comment: So I would put both bits of code in my tap count m file?  do I need to put anything in the h file?

Comment: You don't have to put anything in your .h file; you can put it all in the .m, though you might want to also save the number in your app delegate, like in `applicationWillResignActive:`.

Comment: I have found applicationWillResignActive in the app delegate, what do I put under? sorry i'm new to Xcode...Also reg code mentioned above do I put under viewDidload?

Comment: You can put the code for saving the value to `NSUserDefaults` in there (the first bit of code). That way, your value will be saved if a call comes in or the home button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `viewDidUnload` and `NSUserDefaults`:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:count forKey:@"tapCount"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

In addition to the above being in your view controller, you'll need some set up in your AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // initialize defaults
    NSString *dateKey    = @"dateKey";
    NSDate *lastRead    = (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:dateKey];
    if (lastRead == nil)     // App first run: set up user defaults.
    {
        NSDictionary *appDefaults  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSDate date], dateKey, nil];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:dateKey];

    tapcounter *tapViewController = [[tapcounter alloc] init]; 

    if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(setRootViewController:)]) {
        window.rootViewController = tapViewController;
    } else {
        [window addSubview:tapViewController.view];
    }

    [window addSubview:tapViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Note that `viewDidUnload` is deprecated since iOS 6; you should override the `dealloc` method in the view controller instead.

Comment: Thanks, John! You're right, of course. Do you think `ViewWillDisappear()` would make an appropriate replacement?

Comment: Yes, `viewWillDisappear` is fine as well. Apple's documentation states that _Subclasses can override this method and use it to commit editing changes..._

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I'm getting quite a few errors when pasting the 2nd bit of code in the App delegate m file.  'Use of undefined identifier date key' - being one of the errors.

Comment: Strage. That code comes from a full functioning app. I've updated my answer to include the rest of the method, not sure that'll be much help though. Which lines specifically are giving you errors?

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it looks like there's something above the declaration of our datekey string that's throwing everything off. A line that hasn't been completed. Can you include more of the screen in your screenshot?

Comment: more of the screen is now displayed on the screenshot

Comment: There it is! You need an opening `{` on the method. Right after `launchOptions` on the same line or the next one down. Doesn't matter which.

Comment: In addition `yourViewController` needs to replaced with the name of your primary view controller, after initializing it. Edited my answer to reflect.

and don't forget  `#import "tapcounter.h"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27577/discussion-between-mustafa-and-joebydesign)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `NSUserDefaults`. Here is how to implement it :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:counter forKey:@"count"] //set the value

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"count"] //get the value
```

More information about `NSUserDefaults` with a tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/).

Answer (score 1):

Use iCloud ;)  It's overkill, but its great for learning.

Here is a tutorial.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1